# Still getting incomplete XML errors from remote (PHP)

Tags: php, xml

```
TERMS: 
GD = Godaddy
SO = Stackoverflow
```

I've been doing some research on how to parse remote xml files (and caching). The remote XML in question is 8-10mb, so not REALLY that big, but when I create websites to access it, the same problem occurs(I host on GD, but test locally - locally not much of an issue, GD very frequent), the XML gets cut off too soon, resulting in an incomplete file. GD will not let me refresh, and locally it usually works the 2nd or 3rd time. Here is the following methods I have used over the years in order of oldest to most recent (2017). Much of what I found, except the recent one, has been here at SO.

This one used to work when the xml was smaller years ago:

```
COPY(REMOTE, DEST);// simple :-)
```

After about a year or so ago I noticed that was failing more and more, so I switched to this (short term):

```
    function download($src, $dst) 
    {
        $dst = GAME_CACHE_ROOT.$dst;

        $f = fopen($src, 'rb');
        $o = fopen($dst, 'wb');
        while (!feof($f)) {
            if (fwrite($o, fread($f, 2048)) === FALSE) {
                   return 1;
            }
        }
        fclose($f);
        fclose($o);
        return 0;
}
```

For the most part that works fairly well, but eventually got messy again.

Skipping some other hack ways, I came upon this one, which SHOULD have worked, but only luck with local, GD it worked once or twice and is now failing again

```
$xmlFile = $POST['xmlFile']; 
    $reader = new XMLReader(); //load the selected XML file to the DOM 
    //$reader->open('saved/'.$xmlFile); // could be remote bfg
    $reader->open(BFG_REMOTE_XML);

    while ($reader->read()): 
        if ($reader->nodeType XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name 'game'){ 
            $node = new SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXML()); 
            $info = $node->elementName; //push those values to an array for evaluation arraypush($info,$callStack); 
        } 
    endwhile;
```

(try not to squawk at the "end..." controls, in bigger programs I find them easier to track - personal preference).  That did not work well as intended so switched to the following:

```
// GRAB THE NEW DATA FROM HOST.
        $xml =  "http://rss.*****.com/rss.php?username=*****&type=6&locale=en&gametype=pc";
        $file = 'big.xml';      

        $reader = new XMLReader();// Stream it...
        $reader->open($xml);
        while($reader->read()){

            if( $reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'game'){
                $game = new SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXML());

// process game as needed
// ..rest of file....
```

This works REALLY well locally, but only a few times on GD, the error I kept getting was standard:

```
Warning: XMLReader::readOuterXml(): http://rss.*****.com/rss.php?username=*****&type=6&locale=en&gametype=pc:50384: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in /home/*****/public_html/functions/cron.php on line 39

Warning: XMLReader::readOuterXml(): amename>Final Cut: Death on the Silver Screen Collector&#039;s Edition</gamename in /home/*****/public_html/functions/cron.php on line 39

Warning: XMLReader::readOuterXml(): ^ in /home/*****/public_html/functions/cron.php on line 39

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/*****/public_html/functions/cron.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /home/*****/public_html/functions/cron.php(39): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 /home/klyxmaster/public_html/functions/cron.php(168): updatedb(900) #2 {main} thrown in /home/*****/public_html/functions/cron.php on line 39
```

As you can tell, this error is simply that the file is incomplete (I verified it in a text editor, and sure enough, its randomly chopped off.

What am I missing? I am sure I have all they ways of grabbing a large XML file remotely.

Comment: Try to increase the [default_socket_timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout) to a higher number. Or change hosting.

Comment: HMM no luck with that, hate to change hosting - been with them for almost 10yrs - just this particular xml.